# using AsyncTask but not being able to update a view using onPostExecute method

Tags: android, listview, rest, asynchronous, android-actionbar

I am using AsyncTask on one of my classes, but am not able to update a view using onPostExecute method. On main class I am using ActionBar changing tabs to results tab. where will the results of a query show up in a list format. I am using restful service and am successfully getting a list back from the server. I am trying to update the results tab (located in main class) to show up the results of a query. so far not successful, any help will be be greatly appreciated, thanks.

PS. I do get the onPostExecute method running after the changing to results tab and getting a list from server, just not able to update the view in main from the AsyncTask class. I also need to mention that I have also the onProgressUpdate method "I just output a string in the log cat to make sure it is being called". and also the doInBackground method all work fine, just not able to update the view correctly. Also since I'm updating main from a different class I made the listview and adapter static, so I can call them from the asyncTask class, In my mind this makes sense, but this may be where I'm wrong, you can see that on the onPostExecute method. thanks.

main class OnCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


       bar = getActionBar();
       bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Basic\nSearch").setTabListener(this));
       bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Advanced\nSearch").setTabListener(this));
       bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Results").setTabListener(this));
       //bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Exit").setTabListener(this));

       bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
       bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
       bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
       // remove the activity title to make space for tabs
       bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
       bar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    }
```

method in main class that changes tab to results tab and queries server:

```
public void basicSubmitButton(View view) throws InterruptedException {
        String query = myBasicEditText.getText().toString();
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);
        ReadWebpageAsyncTask basicSubmission = new ReadWebpageAsyncTask();
        basicSubmission.query(query);
    }
```

asyncTask method Oncreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.results);

    }
```

onPostExecute method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             Hummedia.myListView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lv);
             Hummedia.myListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
             Hummedia.myListView.clearChoices();

                Hummedia.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ReadWebpageAsyncTask.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        mediaList);
                //wait();
                Hummedia.myListView.setAdapter(Hummedia.adapter);
         }
```

and here is the Stack trace output when it tries to update the view in main via the onPostExecute method:

```
12-26 18:21:48.916: D/AndroidRuntime(536): Shutting down VM
12-26 18:21:48.916: W/dalvikvm(536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409951f8)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at edu.byu.hummedia.ReadWebpageAsyncTask$DownloadWebPageTask.onPostExecute(ReadWebpageAsyncTask.java:132)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at edu.byu.hummedia.ReadWebpageAsyncTask$DownloadWebPageTask.onPostExecute(ReadWebpageAsyncTask.java:1)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-26 18:21:49.067: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your activity not being attached to a window. (The relevant line of Activity.java is `getWindow().findViewById(id);`.) Since you're switching tab views when you click on the button that launches the AsyncTask, I think this is what's causing the problem.

You'll have to organize your updates to account for this. Try modifying the AsyncTask to call just post a call-back to your activity. In your activity, you can track the window attachment status by overriding `onAttachedToWindow` and `onDetachedFromWindow` and can either make the changes immediately or wait until it is attached.